# Send Bitcoin programmatically from my iPhone app

Tags: bitcoind, ios

I want to allow users to buy stuff with Bitcoin in my iPhone app. I don't want to use things such as Coinbase or Stripe, I want to send the Bitcoin programmatically. I'm pretty new to Bitcoin but as far as I know, I have these options:

1) https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api. Will this allow the users of my app to send Bitcoin to another by simply doing API calls?

2) Creating my own backend and running the Bitcoin daemon in my server.

Do I have another option? Which one is better? Other comments or suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should know that bypassing Apple's 30% surcharge on all IAP like this will get you banned from the app store.